# Put encodeBase64 message in Mysql when I get this message I have different result

Tags: java, mysql, database, java-8

*I have Problem when i write some message 'abc' i have value into database 'UDHG&*#BDlDd' but when i red and decode this messaage i have '???'*

```
@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return String(Base64.encodeBase64(message.getBytes())) : null;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        byte[] base64 = message.getBytes();
        this.body = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(base64));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Unicode Transformation Format: UTF-8

`<String>.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))`

Answer (score 0):

getBytes() : This method encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the **platform's default charset,** storing the result into a new byte array.

Perhaps differs your platform charset from the one used by the database.